# (Python Code) Inside function call another function in OpenERP v7?

Tags: python, function, odoo

I have one function to compare two different fields:

**FUNCTION A:**

```
    def on_change_expected_qty(self, cr, uid, ids, finish_product_quantity):
            res = {}
            for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
                expected_qty = 0.0
                for line_rec in rec.bom_lines:
                    expected_qty += line_rec.product_qty or 0.0
                if finish_product_quantity != expected_qty:
                    if finish_product_quantity > expected_qty:
                        tot_produce = finish_product_quantity - expected_qty
                        res['remarks'] = 'Finish product is produce EXTRA ' + str(tot_produce) +  str(rec.product_uom.name)
                    else:
                        tot_produce = expected_qty - finish_product_quantity
                        res['remarks'] = 'Finish product is produce LESS ' + str(tot_produce) +  str(rec.product_uom.name)

            return {'value':res}
```

Then I have another function which is to calculate the unit cost:

**FUNCTION B:**

```
 def get_unit_cost_calculation(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
        res = {}
        for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            total_unit_cost = 0.0
            if rec.total_production_cost > 0 and rec.finish_product_quantity > 0:
                total_unit_cost = rec.total_production_cost / rec.finish_product_quantity
            res.update({rec.id : total_unit_cost})
        return res
```

How can I call the FUNCTION A in my FUNCTION B after my FUNCTION B is finish calculate the unit cost?

Please help and advise.

Thank you.

Comment: What problem are you having? You simply call the function instead of returning res

Comment: actually I have add this line `on_change_expected_qty(cr.finish_product_quantity)` in my FUNCTION B. But it show me this error `NameError: global name 'on_change_expected_qty' is not defined`. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call it as

```
self.on_change_expected_qty(cr, uid, [rec.id], rec.finish_product_quantity)
```

Comment: Dear Prajul, I have add this logic code into my FUNCTION B after the line of `res.update({rec.id : total_unit_cost})`. It is don't have any error but I don't know why my **remark** field don't have any word although it have call my FUNCTION A? Please advise.

Comment: Anything I need to do the changes in my FUNCTION A in order for my **remarks** field will store the value I want after the FUNCTION A has been called in FUNCTION B. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please check weather `if finish_product_quantity != expected_qty:` is satisfied in your code. Please past your code so that i could have a look...

Comment: Hi Prajul, yup I have add print into my code to check on it and is satisfied: `/Nov/2013 09:48:13] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/mrp.production.output:write HTTP/1.1" 200 -
finish_product_quantity---------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>> 330.0
expected_qty--------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>> 634.0
2013-11-06 09:48:14,063 25551 INFO SydneyCakeHouseDB werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2013 09:48:14] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/mrp.production.output:read HTTP/1.1" 200 -` Please refer to the FUNCTION A code on top that I have post.

Comment: Based on the print result previously, It have pass through the coding for : `if finish_product_quantity != expected_qty:` so it suppose will go to run this line of code: `res['remarks'] = 'Finish product is produce LESS ' + str(tot_produce) +  str(rec.product_uom.name)`. Please advise.

Comment: Hi, So you want to change the value of the field remark after the execution of the function get_unit_cost_calculation???

Comment: Hi, Triggering the onchange event might be difficult. But there is another solution. You can write in to the field "remark" from your functional field function. ie; you have to merge both function A and B in to one.

Comment: Hi Prajul, you mean I use the FUNCTION A then write into my remark field then in the FUNCTION A, I add in my FUNCTION B whic allow to pass to another field name called total_unit_cost? This is what you mean? If you able to show me how the logic code how it look like is the best. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: We can use both Function A and B. After `res.update({rec.id : total_unit_cost})`, add `res.update({rec.id : total_unit_cost}) onchange_data = self.on_change_expected_qty(cr, uid, [rec.id], rec.finish_product_quantity) if onchange_data.get('value', False): onchange_value = onchange_data['value'] remark = onchange_value.get('remark','') self.write(cr, uid, res.id, {'remark': remark}, context=context) return res`

Comment: Thank you Prajul. You help me again. Thank you again.